# Different miner speeds but have almost the same accepted

Tags: xmrig

I have two nodes. A's speed is 48 KH/s, B's speed is 33 KH/s.
But A's accepted is 1417-1568, B's accepted is 1427-1614.

Does that mean A and B get the same rewards, or does B get much more than A?

Comment: The 2 answers are all good.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume by nodes you mean pool miners.

Mining is a random search, so just because you search faster does not mean you always find faster, though in the long run it will tend to that.

Imagine you and a friend both have a bunch of coins, and you're looking for one from the year 1960. You can check a coin a second. Your friend can check a coin every two seconds. You go twice as fast. But your friend might still find more if lucky. In the long run though, you'll find more.

This is the same thing here. Wait long enough, and the number of shares should start matching the expected ratio.

As for how much monero you'll get, the pool does not know your hash rate, it can only infer it based on how fast you find shares. It's as if you had a third person who collected all those coins from 1960 you and your friend find, and tried to guess who can go through coins faster. He doesn't know how fast you both go, but can only estimate based on how quickly each of you find a 1960 coin.

So the amount of monero you'll get will be based on accepted shares, and will go up and down with each miner's luck.

Comment: Is there any way to improve the luck?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Doing so would imply you broke randomx, which was designed to avoid this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Not all shares are equal. A share is a submission of work at a given difficulty target.

A simplified example:

Imagine two miners A and B. A mines at ~5 kh/s and B mines at ~10 kh/s. The pool will adjust the difficulty target for each miner so that they each submit work every ~30 seconds. So after ~10 minutes of mining, both A and B will each have submitted ~20 shares. But because B's share difficulty target would be twice that of A's, B would be rewarded twice as much A.

Thus *shares* are rewarded based on quality, not quantity.

Comment: The pool doesn't send the difficulty to XMRig. How the XMRig get it?  It's that mean more difficulty, the target is more littler?

Comment: The pool does send the difficulty to the miner.

Comment: The pool sets the difficulty in the `target` field of the job.